# I'm getting following error during forgot password email sending err = javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException here is my code

Tags: java, servlets

I'm getting following error during forgot password email sending  err = javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
here is my code 
How to reslove this problem

```
protected void sendMail(String email,String activationLink,String msg){

java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
     properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
     javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties);




     try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);


        message.setContent("<h1>Below is your "+msg+" Code</h1>"
        + "<a href='"+activationLink+"'> Click here to "+msg+" your account </a> "
        + ""
        + "","text/html" );
        message.setSubject(msg);

        InternetAddress sender = new InternetAddress("email", "password");
         InternetAddress receiver = new InternetAddress(email);
        message.setFrom(sender);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, receiver);
         message.saveChanges();

        javax.mail.Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "myemailaddress", "password");
         transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err = " + e);
     }



 }﻿
```

Comment: By sending the correct user/password pair?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to have the proper parameter values over here:

```
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "myemailaddress", "password");
```

and furthermore, [as of this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en), the port for dynamical IP addresses is different, please read this intro first.

Comment: Yes i'm sure there is a proper parameter values

Comment: `AuthenticationError` means: Either username/password is wrong or you are denied access by other means. You can't argue with this error message ...